# Best workflow/tools to migrate feature from older version?

Tags: git, version-control

A feature has been added to an old version of our application to satisfy a customer request. Now, this feature has to be added to the current version.

Given that the changes in the feature are quite numerous, are there any tools to facilitate this migration besides cherry-picking commits or merging manually? There is a comprehensive test suite for this application but doing this by hand is time consuming and prone to errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could still use [`git-cherry-pick (1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html). It supports passing a set of commits in the `A..B` form.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/679227

You could use tags to specify the range more easily, but it could be done with commit hashes as well.

Comment: In my case this is unnecessary, the commits for the new feature in the old version were squashed into one massive commit which I have to merge manually.